# HTML5 Next and Previous Audio using nofitication from Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-audio

I am working on a music player. I am successfully able to play audio from urls and getting notification of the playing music.

[image]

I can use the play/pause button to play/pause the music ( it worked automatically), but I don't know how to implement the next and previous buttons.
I am using latest version of Chrome (84.0.4147.89).

[Edit 1]

Minimum Reproducible Code:

```
<html>
      <head>
        <title>Xt3m1xMus1c</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <audio id="song" src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3" autoplay></audio>
      </body>
      <script>
          function nextSong() {
             // Need to call this function when I press the next button on the notification
             document.getElementById("song").setAttribute('src', "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3");
          }
      </script>
</html>
```

Comment: That is a nice image but where is your code?  Try to create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ChrisL Added the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These buttons can be controlled with the [Media Session API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API). To implement the previous and next buttons you need to set the corresponding action handlers.

```
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler(
    'nexttrack',
    () => { /* Your code to play the next track. */ }
);
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler(
    'previoustrack',
    () => { /* Your code to play the previous track. */ }
);
```

But I think the buttons shown in the picture are the `'seekbackward'` and `'seekforward'` buttons.